# Change font weight and opacity with Javascript

Tags: addeventlistener

I'm super new to Javascript and I need help solving this problem.

I have created a list and I would like the font weight of the selected element to be bold and the opacity of the non-selected element dropping to .5 on the click.

I understood that I need to use an eventlistener "click" but I´m pretty stucked, if someone can give me some hints will be greatly, greatly, appreciated.

```
<div class="media">
    <ul>
        <li class="language" id="italian">Italian</li>
        <li class="language" id="english">English</li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: the javascript object property 'style' of type CSSStyleDeclaration can give you all these features. The properties can be modified and changes can take effect almost immediately. But is not always a best practice to do more styling with this, since is slow. You can always just load a CSS script to help do the styling for you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly what you are trying but changing CSS via java script, one way

```
<li class="language" id="selectedElement">Italian</li>
<li class="language" id="nonSelectedElement">Italian</li>

function click() {
document.getElementById("selectedElement").style.fontWeight = "bold";
document.getElementById("nonSelectedElement").style.opacity = 0.5;
}
```